# Problem with many $filter parameters

Tags: 2013, rest, filter

The query below returns a 404 error because there are two many $filter parameters. Can I increase the number of $filter parameters permitted? How can I improve this query?

```
http://mysite/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('SomeList')/items?$filter=((ID eq 
'228') or (ID eq '118') or (ID eq '117') or (ID eq '75') or (ID eq '116') or (
ID eq '74') or (ID eq '115') or (ID eq '114') or (ID eq '113') or (ID eq '73') 
or (ID eq '112') or (ID eq '109') or (ID eq '110') or (ID eq '122') or (ID eq 
'121') or (ID eq '5') or (ID eq '111') or (ID eq '120') or (ID eq '119') or (
ID eq '125') or (ID eq '211') or (ID eq '71') or (ID eq '72') or (ID eq '123') 
or (ID eq '124') or (ID eq '126') or (ID eq '434') or (ID eq '433') or (ID eq 
'432') or (ID eq '431') or (ID eq '430') or (ID eq '406') or (ID eq '405') or (
ID eq '404') or (ID eq '403') or (ID eq '419') or (ID eq '418') or (ID eq 
'417') or (ID eq '394') or (ID eq '416') or (ID eq '395') or (ID eq '415') or (
ID eq '439') or (ID eq '24') or (ID eq '387') or (ID eq '421') or (ID eq 
'388') or (ID eq '393') or (ID eq '420') or (ID eq '436') or (ID eq '438') or (
ID eq '440') or (ID eq '435') or (ID eq '429') or (ID eq '428') or (ID eq 
'427') or (ID eq '396') or (ID eq '426') or (ID eq '402') or (ID eq '401') or (
ID eq '400') or (ID eq '399') or (ID eq '398') or (ID eq '425') or (ID eq 
'424') or (ID eq '423') or (ID eq '441') or (ID eq '422') or (ID eq '397') or (
ID eq '410') or (ID eq '409') or (ID eq '408') or (ID eq '389') or (ID eq 
'392') or (ID eq '407') or (ID eq '414') or (ID eq '437') or (ID eq '413') or (
ID eq '412') or (ID eq '411'))&$orderby=Test_x0020_Date 
desc&$expand=AttachmentFiles&
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably create a column (Flagged of type Yes/No) in the list to act as a field to filter on versus ORing all that together. Tick all the boxes to Yes for those items and then it becomes something like:

```
http://mysite/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('SomeList')/items?$filter=((Flagged eq true)&$orderby=Test_x0020_Date desc&$expand=AttachmentFiles&
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to replace REST query,utilize CAML query instead of `filter` query option as demonstrated below:

Endpoint:

POST `/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('<list title>')/getitems`

```
{  
       'query' : {
            '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.CamlQuery' }, 
            'ViewXml' : query
       }
}
```

where query:

```
<View>
  <Query>
    <Where>
      <In>
        <FieldRef Name="ID" />
        <Values>
           <Value Type="Number">1</Value>
           .
           .
           <Value Type="Number">N</Value>
        </Values>
      </In>
    </Where>
  </Query>
</View>
```

**JavaScript example**

```
function createIDSelectionQuery(values)
{
   var query = '<View><Query><Where><In><FieldRef Name="ID" /><Values>'; 
   for(var i = 0; i < values.length;i++){
       query+= '<Value Type="Number">' + values[i] + '</Value>';  
   }                   
   query+=  '</Values></In></Where></Query></View>';
   return query;          
}

var query = createIDSelectionQuery([1,2,3]);             
getListItems(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl,'Documents',query)
.done(function(data)
{
     var items = data.d.results;
     for(var i = 0; i < items.length;i++) {
         console.log(items[i].Title);
     }    
})
.fail(
function(error){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
});
```

where

```
function getListItems(webUrl,listTitle, viewXml) 
{
    var url = webUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listTitle + "')/getitems"; 
    var queryPayload = {  
               'query' : {
                      '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.CamlQuery' }, 
                      'ViewXml' : viewXml
               }
    };

    return $.ajax({
           url: url,
           method: "POST",
           data: JSON.stringify(queryPayload),
           headers: {
              "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
              "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
              "content-type": "application/json; odata=verbose"
           }
     });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, my case is a bit different in that I need to use REST in order to expand attachment files. I'm now thinking of doing some kind of paging.